# Seg fault trying to access an object member

Tags: c++, oop

Trying to follow the example showed in this article http://goo.gl/DvglYv I've designed the following class:

Bridge.h :

```
class Bridge {
public:
    IfFrameSender *pFrmSender;
    std::string senderName;
    ...
    Bridge(cfg_settings cfg_sett);
    void saveFrame(cv::Mat &cvFrm, uint XOff, uint YOff);
    ...
}
```

In particular pFrmSender is a pointer to a virtual class, IfFrameSender.

In Bridge.cpp I've defined the constructor:

```
Bridge::Bridge(cfg_settings cfg_sett)
{
    ...
    /* Instantiates a sender_by_socket object using a factory */
    IfFrameSender *pFrmSender = FrameSenderFactory::Get()->CreateFrameSender("FrameSenderBySocket"); 
    ...
}
```

and the method:

```
void Bridge::saveFrame(cv::Mat &cvFrm, uint XOff, uint YOff)
{
    ...
    pFrmSender->sendFrame(...);
    ...
}
```

Well, I get a seg fault when I try to invoke pFrmSender. I've done a little of debug and I've discovered that in the Bridge::saveFrame method that member has an incorrect memory address (CCCCCCCC) while in the constructor it's correctly instatiated, I've printed its memory address and it seems to be consistent.

I've declared that member in the header file, so I supposed it would be visible by any method of the Bridge class. Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to keep debugging and narrowing down the problem. Quite a lot!

Comment: `IfFrameSender *pFrmSender = FrameSenderFactory::...` <= hides the class member. Remove the `IfFrameSender *` and just assign to the class member.

Comment: CCCCCCCC is uninitialized stack memory. Set/clear your variables before you use them; don't assumed it's done for you.

Comment: Ok, I already suspected that my variable remains in a uninitialized state, simply I don't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is :

```
Bridge::Bridge(cfg_settings cfg_sett)
{

  /* Following is a temporary variable, which is destroyed after this ctor returns */
  IfFrameSender *pFrmSender = FrameSenderFactory::Get()->CreateFrameSender("FrameSenderBySocket"); 
}
```

you are creating a new (temporary) `IfFrameSender *` in the constructor, which will be destroyed once the constructor returns. Instead, initialize the one declared as class member:

```
Bridge::Bridge(cfg_settings cfg_sett)
{
  this->pFrmSender = FrameSenderFactory::Get()->CreateFrameSender("FrameSenderBySocket"); 
}
```

Also it is better practice to check for `null` when using a pointer:

```
void Bridge::saveFrame(cv::Mat &cvFrm, uint XOff, uint YOff){

   if(pFrmSender!=nullptr) 
      pFrmSender->sendFrame(...);
 }
```

Although, I guess in this case if `pFrmSender` can not be constructed, then `Bridge::Bridge()` may throw exception if creating itself is meaningless.

Comment: Hopefully making this answer more clear: `pFrmSender` is a _local_ inside the constructor. Based on its use in `Bridge::saveFrame` it's also a class member, but only the constructor local has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Bridge::Bridge(cfg_settings cfg_sett) :
    pFrmSender(FrameSenderFactory::Get()->CreateFrameSender("FrameSenderBySocket"))
{

}
```

This way you're actually initializing your class member.